# Why is this valid Python?

Tags: python

This code:

```
bounding_box = (
    -122.43687629699707, 37.743774801147126
    -122.3822021484375, 37.80123932755579
)
```

produces the following value:

```
(-122.43687629699707, -84.63842734729037, 37.80123932755579)
```

There are three values because I forgot a trailing comma on the first line. Surprisingly, Python accepts this and adds the second and third numbers together!

Is this something like [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/string-catenation.html) but for numbers? Why would this ever be the desired behavior?

Answer (score 10):

What happens is simple. In the following assignment

```
bounding_box = (
    -122.43687629699707, 37.743774801147126
    -122.3822021484375, 37.80123932755579
)
```

Is equivalent to

```
bounding_box = (-122.43687629699707, **37.743774801147126-122.3822021484375**, 37.80123932755579)
```

So, the two values are just being subtracted, and hence produce a 3-tuple.

Answer (score 3):

Without the newlines, and dropping the decimals for clarity:

```
bounding_box = (-122, 37 - 122, 37 )
```

In other words, what was supposed to be a comma then unary minus was parsed as a subtraction operator.

Comment: Yep! This is a good reason to run a linter. For example, PyCharm shows this complaint about the third number: "PEP8: missing whitespace around operator". While it's not getting at the root cause (a missing comma), it's at least a tip-off that something is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

You have a newline, but no new indent. It doesn't throw an error because there is no indentation issues, and it doesn't even acknowledge the newline when doing the subtraction.

What if you're trying to keep your text all within the window? The delimiter between values is a comma, not a newline. That's why this is the desired behaviour.